# Test should find a specific icon

Tags: testing, flutter, icons

How can I test that it should find a specific Icon like Icons.visibility?
This is my test:

```
  testWidgets(
      'Should find visibility_off icon',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await _buildApp(tester);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byWidget(Icon(Icons.visibility)), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `byIcon` method on the `Finder` object.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/byIcon.html

```
testWidgets('Should find visibility_off icon', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await _buildApp(tester);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  expect(find.byIcon(Icons.visibility), findsOneWidget);
});
```